# If past date innerHTML = string, jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im trying to write a function that counts down to a date which works fine but once the date is passed my countdown keeps on going into the - numerals.

After 1 day is left I need it to say 'Today' and after its passed I need it to say 'Finished'

I've made fiddle I hope can explain it better, thanks

http://jsfiddle.net/beDks/3/

Comment: We all have needs, but what is your question?

Comment: I have fixed your Fiddle. It did not only contain several syntax errors, but you were also mixing jQuery with "pure" Javascript. Was that intended, an oversight, of ignorance?

Comment: I have an [example](http://zdravko.genov.me/MayanCalendar.html) like this, only without saying today.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should do the trick. Not tested, your mileage may vary etc...

```
var dateText = '';
if (e_days_left == 1) {
   dateText = 'Today';
} else if (timeLeft <= 0) {
   dateText = 'Finished';
} else {
   dateText = daysLeft.toString();
}
document.getElementById('cdown').innerHTML = dateText;
```

Comment: It doesnt seem to work, I've tried the following too with no luck 

if($daysleft > '1') {
    echo "<p>its today</p>";
}
elseif($daysleft == '0') {
    echo "<p>event has passed</p>";
}

Answer (score 0):

Is it what you are looking for: http://jsfiddle.net/Wf223/2/

```
today = new Date();
expo = new Date("November 01, 2011");
var one_day=1000*60*60*24
var daysLeft = Math.ceil((expo.getTime()-today.getTime())/(one_day));
 if(daysLeft === 0){
     alert("today");
 }else if(daysLeft < 0){
     alert('passed');
 }
```